# React Router v4 baseName and custom history

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I would like to assign a basename to my routes, which I can with BrowserRouter.

I would also however like to specify a custom history so I can programatically navigate my users. Which I can do, with Router.

I can't however, do both. Is it possible to extend one of the routers to support this or wrap function round it to add this?

My current setup is this -

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

import createHistory from './history';

import Navigation from './components/navigation/Navigation';

import PrivateRoute from './components/private-route/PrivateRoute';

import Home from './containers/home/Home';
import PageTwo from './components/pageTwo/PageTwo';
import Callback from './components/callback/Callback';
import Login from './components/login/Login';

export default () => (
  <Router history={createHistory}>
    <div>
      <Navigation />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/callback" component={Callback} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/page-two" component={PageTwo} />
        <Redirect to="/" />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

However I'd love to achieve something such as -

```
<Router history={createHistory} basename="foo">
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[You can](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter):

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/your/app">
  <App/>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Or to directly configure the `history` object:

```
import { Router } from 'react-router';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

const history = createBrowserHistory({ basename: '/your/app' });

<Router history={history}>
  <App />
</Router>
```

Comment: Awesome. But could you explain what are differences ? or when to use one over another

Comment: @MardONE according to [the official documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router) **The most common use-case for using the low-level <Router> is to synchronize a custom history with a state management lib like Redux or Mobx. Note that this is not required to use state management libs alongside React Router, it’s only for deep integration.** With **Router** and custom **history** object you can do things like listening to location changes - `history.listen((location, action) => {});`