# props.match.params.id works when I am testing but does not when I deploy in github with gh-pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, github-pages, react-router-dom

I am using a `Route` like `<Route path="/:boardID" component={Board} />` and I am using the `boardID` from Board component taking it from `this.props.match.params.boardID`. It works fine when I test it with `npm start`. But it doesn't work when I deploy it to github pages with `npm run deploy`.

I understand that when I test, the url is `localhost:3000/boardID-00` and in case of github pages deployment, it becomes `username.github.io/projectname/boardID-00` which causes the problem. Is there a way so that it works for both cases? So, that I can fetch `boardID` in both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled all day with this earlier this week.

If you're using `HashRouter` as your Router, your routes should work after being deployed to GitHub Pages.

If you're using `BrowserRouter` as your Router, GitHub Pages is not designed to work with client-side routing without the help of a `#`. I tried ludwiguer's suggestion, and it didn't work for me, although maybe it will work for others.

[This article](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-cannot-get-url-refresh/) helped me out, and I ended up using Firebase Hosting, making sure to answer "yes" in the initialization process when the CLI asks `Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)?`

Here is a GitHub issue thread you might want to take a gander at ([Gh-pages deployment problems with react-router](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1765)), but since I didn't want to use `HashRouter`, the only thing that worked for me was to deploy with something other than GitHub pages.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this answer [React Router v4 baseName and custom history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47580538/react-router-v4-basename-and-custom-history)

Basically you can add a **basename** prop to your router depending on your environment

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/projectname">
  <App/>
</BrowserRouter>
```